# How to skip or ignore empty files in python?

Tags: python, excel, file

How can I skip/ignore the empty tdms files (0KB) from entering my final excel file? This is the code I use, however when i opened the Excel sheet I still found out that it collected the empty files.

Does someone has a solution for this?

```
source1 = r'D:FolderX'
location2 = 'c:\data\AM\Desktop\destination'

black_list = ['folder1', 'folder2'] 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source1):
    #Exclude the blacklist folders.
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in black_list]
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".tdms"):
            tdms_path = (os.path.join(root, file)) 
            file_size = os.path.getsize(tdms_path)
            
            if file_size == 0:
                 continue
        metadata = td.read_metadata(tdms_path)
        print(metadata)
        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([metadata.properties.values()], columns=metadata.properties.keys()))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_excel(locatie2 + '\\' + 'final_sheet.xlsx')
```

Comment: @Sushanth Not so sure, how do I implement it into my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discussion with the OP has confirmed that only files ending `.tdms` are required in the output. The problem with the code as it stood was that if the filename did **not** end in `.tdms`, the statements `metadata = ...` and following would still be executed, although they would use the value of the `tdms_path` variable that had been set during an earlier iteration, when a .tdms file had been processed (and the `tdms_path` variable is *always* set when a `.tdms` file is processed, regardless of whether the size is zero or non-zero).  The bug is fixed by introducing an `else` block with a `continue` statement, so that any non-`.tdms` files do not trigger any further processing.

```
import os    # <=========  import added here

source1 = r'D:FolderX'
location2 = 'c:\data\AM\Desktop\destination'

black_list = ['folder1', 'folder2'] 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source1):
    #Exclude the blacklist folders.
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in black_list]
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".tdms"):
            tdms_path = (os.path.join(root, file)) 
            file_size = os.path.getsize(tdms_path)
            if file_size == 0:
                 continue
        else:                    # <=== skip if not a .tdms file
            continue             # <=== (otherwise uses tdms_path from earlier iteration)
        metadata = td.read_metadata(tdms_path)
        print(metadata)
        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([metadata.properties.values()], columns=metadata.properties.keys()))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_excel(locatie2 + '\\' + 'final_sheet.xlsx')
```

A word about how this bug arose, and could have been detected more easily.  On each iteration of the loop, the variable `tdms_path` is sometimes assigned, and sometimes not assigned.  When it is not assigned, the value used may be retained from an earlier iteration.  This adds more room for error.  If the value was explicitly initialised to `None` or similar on each iteration, e.g.:

```
    for file in files:
        tdms_path = None  # <==== *this*
        if file.endswith(".tdms"):
            tdms_path = (os.path.join(root, file)) 
            # ... etc ...
```

then when a non-`.tdms` file was processed, and execution reached the statment `metadata = td.read_metadata(tdms_path)` (because of the bug concerning the missing `else: continue`), the value of `tdms_path` would have been `None` rather than the value from an earlier iteration.  This would have been a lot more obvious to debug.

Comment: Aha Thank you. But I need to delete the ``if file_size == 0:continue`` True?

Comment: I get an error: ``The system cannot find the file specified:``

Comment: @ManCity10 Ah very good point. Let me modify this very slightly. Needs the full path...

Comment: @ManCity10 Sorry about that -- give it a try now.  Doing exactly the same sort of thing that the code already does with `tdms_path` further down.

Comment: Well this is very weird. I can see in the log it reads all the tdms files expect the empty ones. But when it transfers them to the Excel sheet It still takes the empty files with it. Why is that? I dont want empty rows in my Excel.

Comment: Okay, you have a separate bug in your logic. I can fix that for you... Think about what would happen if a file is a zero-size `.tdms` file and then the *next* file is not a `.tdms` file at all.

Comment: If a file is a zero-size tdms file I dont want it transported and if a file is not a tdms file i also dont want it transported. I actually want all the TDMS files who are NOT empty. Did you fix it already?

Comment: Now its fixed bro, thank you. Last 2 questions if you mind. 1. Can I delete the line ``if file_size ==0 continue`` 2. I would love to add a progress bar so I can see how far it has reached, how do I do that?

Comment: @ManCity10 In response to those questions: (1) if you remove that line then you will get the empty files that you want to filter out, (2) sorry but progress bar is too far out of scope for this question, so please ask a separate question if you want.

Comment: But Now it seems I have 2 if statements that will filter out the zero inst that unnecessary ? I already asked a separate question about the progress bar, can you check it? Thx

Comment: @ManCity10 Yes you're right. I have edited the code already and will write a new explanation.

Comment: @ManCity10 I have updated the comments accordingly - please have a good read of what I wrote now.

Comment: Thank you bro. You think its possible to react on my tkinter question? I actually use the same code as this one in there. Would be great !

Comment: @ManCity10 I am probably not best placed to help with questions about tkinter. Hopefully others will respond to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check if a file is empty:

```
import os
if os.stat(file).st_size == 0:
    continue
```

Use this condition in your inner for-loop:

```
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".tdms"):
        tdms_path = (os.path.join(root, file)) 
            
        if os.stat(file).st_size == 0:
            continue
    metadata = td.read_metadata(tdms_path)
    print(metadata)
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([metadata.properties.values()], 
                            columns=metadata.properties.keys()))
```

Comment: I need to do this for more then 100+ files. Your code is just for 1 file i guess.

Comment: Or `os.path.getsize("file")`

Comment: @ManCity10 Yes you would just put it (using `file` instead of `"file"`, and appropriately indented) as the first thing inside the `for file in files` loop

Comment: @alaniwi I used your code above but I received n ``FileNotFoundError``

Comment: Bram - I think I've finally understood what is _really_ going on here - you may be interested to see my answer (now rather edited from how it was before).